# One loop diagram for given interaction term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, self-energy

For a given interaction term, say $\frac12g\varphi^2\psi$, how would one find the one loop diagram that contributes to its self energy of $\varphi$? I think it would just be one propagator going into a vertex, and one coming out. What ultimately is confusing me is the fact that there are two real scalar fields.

Comment: Hello! I have provided an edit to your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @steven1234: the self-energy diagram of $\varphi$ is very similar to the electron self-energy diagram in QED, ie, an electron emits an photon which gets reabsorbed by the same particle, whereas in the question's case it is the $\varphi$-particle emits a $\psi$-particle which gets reabsorbed by the $\varphi$-particle.

Comment: Isn't is like an electron self-energy? An electron line splits in the first vertex into two propagators (electron and photon ones) that meet in the second vertex continued by the electron line. Similarly for $\phi$ and $\psi$ ( $\psi$ being an analogue of the photon field).

Comment: Yes I see now. That's cleared things up. Thank you very much